# UpdatePanel - asyncpostbacktrigger and postbacktrigger with same control but different events

Tags: asp.net, ajax, updatepanel

In my UpdatePanel, the user can page, sort and filter a gridview all using AJAX, then they select a row which causes the post to post back and a textbox to be populated with the rows ID.

Problem is, it seems I can't register both an AsyncPostBackTrigger and a PostBackTrigger to the same control - so how would I accomplish this? Here are my triggers so far:

```
            <Triggers> 
                        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnFilter" EventName="Click" /> 

                             <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="GridView1" EventName="PageIndexChanged" />
                   <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="GridView1" EventName="PageIndexChanging" />
                   <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="GridView1" EventName="Sorting" />
                   <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="GridView1"/>
                    </Triggers>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it is too late but I have a solution. It is no possible to register a synchronous and an asynchronous postback to the same control. What I do is to include a timer in the update panel and add a postback trigger to that timer. So, in the event you want to cause the synchronous postback enable the timer and it'll cause the postback.